# Can you undo the text message notification that gets sent when changing share settings on a Note?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, notes.app, privacy

Say you are working on the draft of a project in an iOS note.

You share the note with a potential collaborator wanting their input.

But then you share the note with someone else who is their competitor.

Then you realize the first person will get a text message that you shared it with their competitor, and want to undo that text message notification.

**Can it be done? Furthermore, can you make sure that if you share a note between two people, they do not know the note is shared from the Notes app?**

Comment: If your company prohibits you from sharing data, information, notes, etc, with a competitor, you may be in violation of your employment agreement and sanctioned by your company, including termination and legal action.

Comment: Ok but it is just an example. It could be people wanting to share a gift list with different family members who don’t like each other, etc.Needing to share a document with two people doesn’t imply wanting to have these people know about each other, the app assumes I want to send a text message - one that cannot be edited or canceled in messages…